# Connecting two Windows XP with MSMQ

Tags: msmq, message-queuing

I have MSMQ installed on two Windows XP computers. Can I configure them to pass messages back and forth, or do I need an MSMQ server in the middle?

If I need an MSMQ server, does the normal MSMQ with Win2003 able to act as that? And then, how do I connect my Windows XP to that Windows 2003 server?  Is it a) On screen admin dialog in the MSMQ plug-in to MMC, b) a config file, c) Active Directory, d) something else?

Thanks,

Neal Walters

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ on Windows XP operate the same as on windows 2003. So you don't need a server. But I think that you are missing something. MSMQ don't connect to one another by themselves. You can think of them as not more than file shares. You need some application to read and write to the queues to make them connect (by sending to remote queue your local msmq is communicating with the remote msmsq).